# Heatmaps in MixPanel

Tags: android, ios, mixpanel

I need to measure some user events and for that i have integrated `MixPanel` in my application.

Everything seems okay but now my requirement is that i need to generate Heatmaps based on some of the event values.

I have checked a lot on `MixPanel` documentation and couldn't find any useful information for it.

I have also reffered this link :https://mixpanel.com/blog/2010/03/22/the-death-of-the-pageview/ and come to know that need to check for some ClickTale service but didn't find any proper documentation for it

My Question is :

1. Does `Mixpanel` provided Heatmap generation feature? If yes then is it in free version or paid version?
2. If it is provides then how can i generate it ?

Can anyone help me with this?